# Changing size of thumbnails in a collection in Shopify

Tags: html, css, json, shopify

I'm trying to help my sister in-law with an issue she's having with her shop and I can't make heads or tails of what is going on.

Her page is here: https://shopboom.com/

If you scroll to the bottom you'll see a featured products section.

This section used to have three items and large thumbnails but she says after installing an app called "Loyalty Lion" they changed to four small pics.

How do you specify the number of items and their thumbnail sizes?

I've been through all the code and I can't figure it out at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is not regarding Loyalty Lion app,

You need to find following js code in your shopify file.

```
$("#flexiselDemo3").flexisel({
    visibleItems: 4,
    itemsToScroll: 1,         
    autoPlay: {
        enable: true,
        interval: 300000,
        pauseOnHover: true
    }        
});
```

And change value of visibleItems 4 to 3.

I hope it will work for you.